# C# Connection And NonQuery Execution To Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

Just wondering if there are any typical issues when using this form of database command/connection. Is there something "better"? Anything else that could possibly help me improve my TSQL/C# skills would be much appreciated! Thank you!

```
private void Approval_Status(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button Approval = (Button)sender;
        /*
         * Boolean determining if the request was approved or denied
         */
        Boolean Status = false;

        if (ValidateApproval(Approval.Text.Trim().ToUpper()) == true)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd0 = new SqlCommand();
            cmd0.Connection = db.con(user.Authority);
            cmd0.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd0.CommandText = "UPDATE [TBL_REQUEST] " +
                "SET [TBL_REQUEST].[REQUEST_STATUS]=@Status, [TBL_REQUEST].[APPROVED_BY]=@Approver, " +
                "[TBL_REQUEST].[DATE_APPROVED]=@Date, [TBL_REQUEST].[PRINTED_NAME]=@Name, " +
                "[TBL_REQUEST].[TITLE]=@Title, [TBL_REQUEST].[PTO_USED]=@Used " +
                "WHERE [TBL_REQUEST].[ID]=@ID; ";
            if (Approval.Text.ToUpper() == codes.RequestApproved)
            {
                cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = codes.RequestApproved;
                Status = true ;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = codes.RequestDenied;
                Status = false;
            }
            cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Approver", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user.User;
            cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
            cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtApproval.Text.Trim();
            cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user.Title;
            cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Used", SqlDbType.Float).Value = (float)nudUsed.Value;
            cmd0.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtID.Text.Trim();
            /*
             * Execute our non-query
             */
            db.conEstablished.Open();
            cmd0.ExecuteNonQuery();
            db.conEstablished.Close();
            /*
             * Dispose our resources
             */
            cmd0.Dispose();
            ClearRequestsPanel();
            /*
             * Inform our user of a successful update
             */
            if (Status == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(msg.RequestApproved);
            }
            else if (Status == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(msg.RequestDenied);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is `db.con`? And the `using` statement is part of the language - it's not a function.

Comment: The typical issue when using this form is forgetting the `cmd0.Dispose()` call, which `using` takes care of. :)

Comment: @David: Not just forgetting it, but failing to put it in a `finally` block...

Comment: Please remember that `x == true => x`. You don't need to compare boolean expression to `true`.

Comment: @IliaG Personally I'm ok with badly named booleans going with that form since `if(Status)` reads slightly worse than `if (Status==true)` Personally I would have rather see well named booleans so it reads nicely `if(IsApproved)` or `if(Approved)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look something like this.  Obviously I've got variables here that are defined elsewhere but hopefully this gives you a better idea of how to use `using`

```
using(var dbconn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var dbcmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedure, dbconn))
    {
        dbcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        dbcmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters.ToArray());
        dbconn.Open();
        return dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for actually answering the question. I was looking for the proper syntax for 'using'.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you may well be trying to create your own connection pooling. Don't do that:

- Use `using` statements for all disposable resources. That includes `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`. That way, even if an exception is thrown, the resource is disposed
- Create a new `SqlConnection` for each database operation, and let the system manage pooling the *real* network connections.

It's not clear what `db.con(...)` and `db.conEstablished` are, but it *sounds* like you've quite possibly got a single connection - which means that you can't use this code safely in a multi-threaded environment. It's fine to have a helper method to create a `SqlConnection`, but it should just create a new one each time, which is then disposed when the operation has been completed.

Additionally, you should start following .NET naming conventions, and this code:

```
if (Status == true)
{
    MessageBox.Show(msg.RequestApproved);
}
else if (Status == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show(msg.RequestDenied);
}
```

... would be better written as:

```
MessageBox.Show(Status ? msg.RequestApproved : msg.RequestDenied);
```

Comment: MessageBox.Show(Status ? msg.RequestApproved : msg.RequestDenied);
...Was helpful! Learned something new, thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaVolearix: Even if you wanted to use the `if` version, it would be better to use `if (Status) { ... } else { ... }`. For one thing, if it's not true it will definitely be false - and it's generally cleaner style IMO to use `if (foo)` or `if (!foo)` rather than `if (foo == true)` or `if (foo == false)`.

Comment: Definitely good to know, I've only been programming C# for two weeks now and everything else past the ABSOLUTE basics has been self taught in general. Things like that don't really get covered in beginner books!

Answer (score 2):

`using` is the "proper" way to handle disposable objects like the SqlConnection.

Part of the problem with your code is that if the query causes an exception, then this line will be skipped, because the exception will break out of the method:

```
cmd0.Dispose();
```

When using `using` the dispose will always be called, even if an exception exits the block (internally it just wraps the code in a `try/catch` and puts the call to `.Dispose()` in the catch block.)

Also you should note that the `SqlConnection` class handles pooling internally. It is not actually a single open network connection to the DB.